# Putting Transition To An open/close elment using css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I currently have a code like this, which on clicking readmore shows the child component but I want to add some transition to it so it looks smooth

```
   import { useState } from "react"
   import { Paper } from "../Paper/paper"
   import './index.css'

export const HiddenCard = (props) => {
    const [show,setShow] = useState(false)

    const handleClick = () => {
        setShow(!show)
    }

    return (
        <Paper>
            <div className="hidden-card-body">
                <p className="Hidden-card-title">
                    TITLE
                </p>
                <div className = {`hidden-card-child ${show?"show":"hide"}`} >
                    {props.children}
                </div>
                <div className="hidden-card-button" onClick={handleClick}>
              {show ? "Read Less ^" : "Read More v"}
            </div>
            </div>
        </Paper>            
    )
}
```

and my css looks like this

```
    .hidden-card-body {
     padding: 40px 32px 64px;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     row-gap: 24px;
    }

.Hidden-card-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.hidden-card-child {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.hidden-card-child.show {
  display: block;
}

.hidden-card-child.hide {
  display: none;
}

.hidden-card-button {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  text-align: left;
  color: #a7202c;
}
```

so when the inner child element gets visible/display it should slowly open like how it happens in a collapsible. How can I do that Transition, is there something that I am missing?

[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: Transitions do not apply to the `display` property. You can use `visibility` and/or `opacity` properties instead.

Comment: I did change it to visibility but then it doesn't quite work as expected, I wanted a the animation to look more like a open and close but it looks as if it takes 1s to appear and 1s to disappear

Answer (score 0):

I can put max height : 0px on close and then when it's open can put max-height to some value say 900px and height auto and put a transition on max height will result in open close eg:
for close:

```
  visibility: hidden;
  max-height: 0px;
  transition: max-height 0.3s;
```

for open:

```
  visibility: visible;
  max-height: 300px;
  height: auto;
  transition: max-height 0.6s;
```